# How to bin geographical data and output the data points included in each bin in matlab

Tags: matlab, bins

I am using Matlab to process seismic data, each one of this assume that corresponds to a specific geographic point (known lat, long). One of the goals is to group points in the Earth's surface which are encompassed by bins of a specific radius (e.g r=10degrees). It doesn't matter if the bins are overlapping. 
I have used the `histr()` Matlab intrinsic function but this outputs the central coordinates in (lat,long) of the resulting bins and the number of data points included in a bin. However, I would also like to label the data points and be able to use these labelled data points in subsequent processing.
What I have used:

```
lt1=load('midlats.dat');
lg1=load('midlons.dat');
len_lt=length(lt1);
len_lg=length(lg1);
nb=1;
[clats,clons,num,wnum] = histr(lt1,lg1,nb);
```

In which nb defines how many bins you need per angular degree.

Is this anywhere close to my goal or I am completely missing the picture???
Anyone having come across something similar? 
Any help/comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: You would have to do it separately for lat and lon but `histc` can also return a index of which bin your data falls into, so you can keep track of what value is in what bin.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought - you will need to define a vector of bin edges (either same for both or different), see the help for `histc`:

```
[nlt, i_lt] = histc(lt1,b_vec1);
[nlg, i_lg] = histc(lg1,b_vec2);
```

Now, cheating - use `sub2ind` to convert `i_lt` and `i_lg`, indexes of which latitude and longitude bins your data is in, into a single index.

```
sz = [length(i_lt),length(i_lg)];
ind = sub2ind(sz,i_lt,i_lg);
```

Any points with the same `ind` are in the same lat + lon bins.  You can then select them by indexing with `ind` e.g. `lg1(ind==1)` and so on.

Comment: I have been working on it using `histc()` however, this doesn't treat the latitudes an longitudes as pairs, but rather as individual values. Therefore, `histc()` used in this context will help us track the lt1, lg1 separately. thanks for your feedback though, it gave me some ideas but i haven't been far yet..

Comment: That's why the `sub2ind` part, to pair them up.